# Best word for mass of uninterrupted material

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm debating with myself about what the best word is for a solid mass of uninterrupted homogeneous material. Usage would be as follows:

> **Example:** That giant slab of granite on top of the mesa is _____; the whole thing is of one piece.
>
> **Counterexample:** I can't say that brick wall is _____; it is made up of many separate pieces connected by mortar.

What would be the best word in the blanks there?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Monolithic](https://lexico.com/en/definition/monolithic), particularly in relation to stone. The word derives from *mono-* (one), and *lith* (stone).

> 1. formed of a single large block of stone.
>      *"later Byzantine columns were monolithic and usually made of marble"*